# CLOSED - Android DatePicker restrict max date

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker

I am trying to create a DatePicker in android for selecting Date of birth of a user. i want to set the year in a way that the age selected from the datepicker is greater than 18 years. For eg. if someone clicks on datetimepicker dialog, he/she should see max year as 1998 as its is equivalent to 18 years.

My code goes like:

```
            dobDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                candidateDob.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dobDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

so for now, the restriction is till the current date. Please help :)

Comment: You didn't even read code. He is already using setMaxDate

Answer (score 3):

See these two lines:

```
newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dobDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You are setting the **maxDate** as the current year. Try something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
dobDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

`dobDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - (long) 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 18);`
But it doesn't take into account leap years, so there's probably some other trick with Calendar

Comment: He could also use the calendar but this answer seems legit

Comment: Thanks. this works :)